# Как подгружаются стили на одностраничных сайтах?

Tags: ajax, html, css

Привет. Допустим, у одностраничного ajax-сайта есть постоянные хедер/футер и основной блок, содержимое которого подгружается через ajax. У каждой подгружаемой страницы свой набор стилей. Как их подгружать? Навскидку есть 3 варианта:

1) Запихнуть все стили в один файл/несколько файлов и подключить их одновременно.
*Минусы:* долгое время первой загрузки, одно пространство имён для идентификаторов и классов.

2) Менять атрибут у тега link:

```
HTML: <link rel='stylesheet' href='1.css' id="style">
JS: document.getElementById('style').setAttribute('href','2.css')
```

*Минусы:* новые стили подгружаются дополнительным get-запросом, получается задержка + такое вообще валидно?

3) Ответ в ajax приходит в виде json: `{"style": "<стили>", "html" : "<Код>"}`.
*Минусы:* обработчик должен каждый раз генерировать/брать откуда-то стили.

Как же поступить? Есть ещё какие-нибудь способы? Пока что самый привлекательный вариант  - 2, тем более браузер, по идее, должен закэшировать файлы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот вопрос вроде как избит, ) всё в один файл, конечно, и грузить то, что необходимо для каждой страницы...

> Запихнуть все стили в один
> файл/несколько файлов и подключить их
> одновременно.
> *Минусы:* долгое время
> первой загрузки, одно пространство
> имён для идентификаторов и классов.

не совсем так...
Каждый CSS-файл, который использует страница вашего сайта, добавляет время и снижает скорость загрузки страницы.

Answer (score 2):

У вас там супер-пупер сайт со стилями в несколько мегабайт?) Просто не заморачивайтесь и пишите все в один файл. Его можно и минифицировать еще.